# laravel one to on hasOne relationship manual foreign key and local key detecting wrong column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two tables

[image]

[image: enter image description hered]

In above table, I want to search ***countries.user_name*** (primary key) and want its isd code from ***isdcodes.code*** where ***isdcodes.country_username*** is the foreign key.

**Country Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'my_id';

public function isdcode(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Isdcode', 'country_username', 'user_name');
} 
}
```

**Route File**

```
Route::get('user/{country}', function ($country){
    return \App\Country::find($country)->isdcode;
});
```

hear I am trying to search india(user_name in countries table)
http://localhost:8000/user/india
*Trying to get property of non-object*
the above result is coz it is trying to search india in my_id but I want to search it in user_name.

http://localhost:8000/user/1
{"isd_id":1,"country_username":"india","code":91,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}

**Really thank you in advance.**

Comment: I think primary key and foreign key assigned on generally on id field not a text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` method uses primary key, so you need to change it to this:

```
return \App\Country::where('user_name', $country)->first()->isdcode;
```

Or do this, if you want to use this column as PK:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_name';
```

Comment: Really Thank you, brother... It worked, I didn't know what exactly find method does. :)